# (half) hyperboloid least squares problem

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, least-squares

I have five equations as follows,
[image]
, where *i* = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and only (*x, y, z*) are unknown. The five equations above are half-side hyperboloids. It could be seen as [image].

I want to find the solution (*x, y, z*). However, it's an over-determined system since the number of equations is more than three. Therefore, I have to use one of the optimization methods, from which I choose least squares.

After searching the Internet, I found a lot of websites talking about nonlinear curve fitting. I still don't know how to find the optimal solution (*x, y, z*). Can anyone teach me how to solve this problem? Or you can give me a reference. I'll appreciate it very much.

Btw, the equations appears in a conference paper *[Sound source localization for automatic camera steering](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5967510)* if you're curious why I bumped into this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm) for that. It has a variety of implementations. Levenberg–Marquardt algorithm minimizes following error functional
$$
E(x, y, z) = \sum_i (T_i - f_i(x, y, z))^2.
$$

Comment: What's your function f_i?

Comment: That's the right hand side of your equations

Comment: Thank you for the answer. :D

Comment: Hi from the future. Google has a rather good [solver](https://github.com/ceres-solver/ceres-solver) for these nonlinear least-squared problems, if one wants to bother with C++ for speed.